# Why is logistic regression using glm giving non-intuitive results?

Tags: r, logistic

I am using the NHANES data to fit a logistic regression model with diagnosis of osteoporosis as the dependent variable and independent variables being vitamin D levels, serum calcium levels, age and gender. It is quite clear that women are much more at risk to have osteoporosis both from a medical point of view as well as what is being in the data. Same is the case with age. As you get older, your risk for osteoporosis increases.

I use NHANES data to build a basic logistic regression model and I find that the coefficient estimates for both age and gender (women) are both negative which means that they have a rather inverse relationship with the risk for osteoporosis - and this doesn't make sense.

Fully reproducible code:

```
    library(tidyverse)
library(RNHANES)
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)

d07 = nhanes_load_data("DEMO_E", "2007-2008") %>%
  select(SEQN, cycle, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR) %>%
  transmute(SEQN=SEQN, wave=cycle, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("VID_E", "2007-2008"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, LBXVIDMS) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD=LBXVIDMS) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("BIOPRO_E", "2007-2008"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, LBXSCA) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium = LBXSCA) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("OSQ_E", "2007-2008"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium, OSQ060) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium, Osteop = OSQ060)


d09 = nhanes_load_data("DEMO_F", "2009-2010") %>%
  select(SEQN, cycle, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR) %>%
  transmute(SEQN=SEQN, wave=cycle, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("VID_F", "2009-2010"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, LBXVIDMS) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD=LBXVIDMS) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("BIOPRO_F", "2009-2010"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD,  LBXSCA) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium = LBXSCA) %>% 
  left_join(nhanes_load_data("OSQ_F", "2009-2010"), by="SEQN") %>%
  select(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium, OSQ060) %>% 
  transmute(SEQN, wave, RIAGENDR, RIDAGEYR, vitD, Calcium, Osteop = OSQ060)

dat = bind_rows(d07, d09) %>% as.data.frame()
dat1 = dat %>% 
  mutate(
    vitD_group = case_when(
      vitD < 20 ~ "3Deficiency",
      vitD >= 20 & vitD < 30 ~ "2Insufficiency",
      vitD >=30 ~ "1Normal"))



dat2 = dat1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(vitD_group), !is.na(Calcium), !is.na(Osteop), Osteop!=9) %>% 
  mutate(Gender = recode_factor(RIAGENDR, 
                                `1` = "Men", 
                                `2` = "Women"),
         Osteop = recode_factor(Osteop, 
                                `1` = 1, 
                                `2` = 0))


#ggplot(dat2, aes(log(RIDAGEYR), fill = Osteop)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
#ggplot(dat2, aes(Calcium, fill = Osteop)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
#ggplot(dat2, aes(vitD, fill = Osteop)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)



fit <- glm(Osteop ~ vitD_group + Calcium + Gender + RIDAGEYR, 
           data = dat2, 
           family = "binomial")
summary(fit)

round(exp(coef(fit)), 2)
```

This is the summary of the fit:

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = Osteop ~ vitD_group + Calcium + Gender + RIDAGEYR, 
    family = "binomial", data = dat2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.4442   0.1019   0.1917   0.3392   1.0126  

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               7.538635   1.049564   7.183 6.84e-13 ***
vitD_group2Insufficiency  0.498426   0.208786   2.387    0.017 *  
vitD_group3Deficiency     0.348931   0.333813   1.045    0.296    
Calcium                   0.084913   0.110822   0.766    0.444    
GenderWomen              -2.073578   0.121172 -17.113  < 2e-16 ***
RIDAGEYR                 -0.071582   0.003225 -22.195  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4750.6  on 10243  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3684.5  on 10238  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3696.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Exploratory analysis of Gender and Osteoporosis:

```
> table(dat2$Osteop, dat2$Gender)

     Men Women
  1   86   547
  0 4899  4712
```

A 2-sample t-test of Age and Osteoporosis:

```
> t.test(RIDAGEYR~Osteop, dat2)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  RIDAGEYR by Osteop
t = 34.091, df = 811.51, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 16.78144 18.83200
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 0 
       66.84834        49.04162
```

It's quite clear from the two exploratory analysis that older people and women are at more risk for osteoporosis. However, the multivariate logistic regression model says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this part of your code

```
mutate(Gender = recode_factor(RIAGENDR, 
                                `1` = "Men", 
                                `2` = "Women"),
         Osteop = recode_factor(Osteop, 
                                `1` = 1, 
                                `2` = 0))
```

you set '2' to 0, but the levels remain in the same order. I suppose osteoporosis is the minority, hence '1' in the original data is osteoporosis. You can see in your dataframe

```
levels(dat2$Osteop)
# returns you
# "1" "0"
```

When you perform the logistic regression, you are seeing the coefficients with respect of being "0" (or 2 in the original dat1 case).

You can see in your exploratory analysis, "0" always come after "1".

Factors in R can be a bit nasty... I would suggest not changing labels, but simply doing

```
dat2 = dat1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(vitD_group), !is.na(Calcium), !is.na(Osteop), Osteop!=9) %>% 
  mutate(Gender = recode_factor(RIAGENDR, 
                                `1` = "Men", 
                                `2` = "Women")
  )
dat2$Osteop = factor(dat2$Osteop,levels=2:1)
fit <- glm(Osteop ~ vitD_group + Calcium + Gender + RIDAGEYR,
data = dat2,family=binomial)
```

This should give you the correct orientation